# How to update a part of a json file that there are duplicates of

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "text": "awd",
      "asin": "adawawf",
      "on": false,
      "console": "Checked out!",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "text": "fafdaw",
      "asin": "AWFawfa",
      "on": false,
      "console": "Out of stock",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "text": "adwawD",
      "asin": "daWDawdafdafaf",
      "on": false,
      "console": "Checking out...",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I go about modifying a specific "console" by 0,1,2 in python.

I was thinking something like

```
dict = {"console": "In stock"}

json.update(dict[2])
```

But I do not think this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
# take your json from string of a file
_json = \
"""{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "text": "awd",
      "asin": "adawawf",
      "on": false,
      "console": "Checked out!",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "text": "fafdaw",
      "asin": "AWFawfa",
      "on": false,
      "console": "Out of stock",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "text": "adwawD",
      "asin": "daWDawdafdafaf",
      "on": false,
      "console": "Checking out...",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}"""

# reads from string to dict object
tasks_json = json.loads(_json)

# changing part
index = 0 # for example

# assign whatever you want
tasks_json["tasks"][index]["console"] = "whatever_you_want"

>>> tasks_json
```

output (`this was modified in memory`)

```
{'tasks': [{'text': 'awd',
   'asin': 'adawawf',
   'on': False,
   'console': 'whatever_you_want', <----------------------||||
   'id': 1},
  {'text': 'fafdaw',
   'asin': 'AWFawfa',
   'on': False,
   'console': 'Out of stock',
   'id': 2},
  {'text': 'adwawD',
   'asin': 'daWDawdafdafaf',
   'on': False,
   'console': 'Checking out...',
   'id': 3}]}
```

Comment: This will work but I was wondering if there is a way to do it with json.update?

Comment: `update()` is part of `dict`. update function only adds new content to the dict, NOT modifying it.

Comment: so you can modify inside content using update. you need to directly access the element.